# Logical matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

So this is a general question, I have been working with R a lot for the past 6 months, and while i love the native data structures, some of the functionality of matrices is a bit unclear to me.

My question is about the way in which R deals with logical matrices. Lets say I have a logical matrix of size `n x n` filled with `TRUE` and `FALSE` statements. 
When I use the  `LogicalMat` to filter `MatA` (both same dimensions):

```
MatA[LogicalMat]
```

Are the `FALSE` values evaluated in some kind of loop in the background? or are they simply skipped like some kind of sparse matrix implementation?

If not, are there any ways to create matrices where some parts of the matrix are never evaluated when filtering?  I'm thinking a linked list could do the same, but i like being able to keep the linear nature of the matrix indexing.
I know that there are packages specifically designed for sparse matrices, but I'm interested in the native structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't forget that matrices are still vectors underneath in R. The only difference between a vector and a matrix is the `dim` attribute.

When you do

```
MatA[LogicalMat]
```

You are performing a `vector` operation, not a `matrix` one. In this case, since `LogicalMat` is a logical vector, this translates to "return the entries in `MatA` for which the corresponding entry in `LogicalMat` is `TRUE`. That will not in general be rectangular, so the result is a vector.

R does have a specific sparse matrix class `sparseMatrix` from the `Matrix` package, though the documentation isn't clear whether this optimises operations of the form `M1[M2]` where `M2` is a sparse matrix. It's probably safer to use numeric vectors to subset rather than sparse logical ones (the function `which` can help you get from one to the other)

Comment: I was aware of this, my question was regarding the actual implementation, when you said "return the entries in MatA for which ..." is the "for" part an actual loop where it actually discretely evaluates  through all boolean values in the vector? or does it actually skip FALSE values entirely?

Comment: it isn't an R-loop, though it is probably implemented as a loop in the C-code underneath R. R has to at least *look* at all the values in `MatA`, otherwise it doesn't know if they are false or not. I've added another paragraph with some more detail on sparse matrices specifically.